# Binary/Qualified name is wrong? Begins with: <any?>$

Tags: java, gradle, annotation-processing

I am running an annotation processor that I have wrote. It ran fine on JDK 8 and now I am experiencing a problem on JDK 12.

I have a `TypeElement` and I want to retrieve its binary name to pass to `Class.forName`.

I use `javax.lang.model.util.Elements.getBinaryName(TypeElement)` and it returns a garbage value `<any?>$OuterClass.InnerClass` instead of the expected `example3.OuterClass$InnerClass`.

I attempted to replace `getBinaryName` with `TypeElement.getQualifiedName` (even though it would not quite work for an inner class) but it gives me the same garbage result. I have tried searching for this issue but most search engines strip all the special characters and give me useless results.

The `TypeElement` was obtained by catching a `MirroredTypeException` like so:

```
try {
    exampleAnnotation.value();
    throw new IllegalStateException("Expected a MirroredTypeException.");
} catch (MirroredTypeException ex) {
    return (TypeElement) types.asElement(ex.getTypeMirror());
}
```

And here is the definition of `ExampleAnnotation`:

```
package example1;

@Target(PACKAGE)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface ExampleAnnotation {
    Class<? extends Derived> value() default Derived.class;

    interface Derived<A extends Annotation> extends Base<A> {
        String foo();
    }
}
```

And here is the instance of the annotation that the processor is accessing in `package-info.java`:

```
@ExampleAnnotation(OuterClass.InnerClass.class)
package example2;
import example1.ExampleAnnotation;
```

I have also tried the fully qualified name `example3.OuterClass.InnerClass.class` but that also results in garbage: `<any?>$example3.OuterClass.InnerClass`.

I doubt it matters but the annotation processors are still marked `@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_8)` and I am running this on Gradle 5.3.1.

I've verified the processorpath contains the jars for packages example1 and example3, including the annotation processors.

I've made no changes to account for the module system so I was thinking maybe that's somehow affecting the code.

Just tried creating a Maven project and am currently unable to reproduce the problem, so there may be an issue with my Gradle configuration, similar to what @Colin Alworth has suggested.

Comment: the `jdk-x` tags are just synonyms for `java-x` tags, and the java-12 tag does exist

Comment: @Timisorean there is nothing wrong with using contractions. Please only suggest edits if they add value to the post.

Comment: Can you show what the processor is actually doing, where this code is coming from? it seems to me like it could be that the class where `@ExampleAnnotation` is being found might not yet be compiled, so the compiler can't work out what `InnerClass` is? Or, that `InnerClass` and its enclosing type aren't themselves yet compiled, so they can't be produced?

Comment: On my phone right now but packages example1 and example3 are compiled into jars and then used in a Gradle project containing package example2. So the annotation and class it references are compiled before being used. I will try an even simpler example today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had recently upgraded to a new version of Gradle and started using the "annotationProcessor" dependencies.

It appears that `<any?>$` is prepended to binary/qualified class names (as it appears in the source) if the class isn't on the `classpath` (or if it isn't imported, or is spelled wrong). I only had the annotation's jar on the `processorpath`.

To alert consumers of my annotation processor of this mistake, I was able to detect it by comparing `TypeElement.asType().getKind() == TypeKind.ERROR` immediately after catching the `MirroredTypeException`.